# creating temp stack to print it in c

Tags: c, stack

current uni student and i have been tasked with creating a stack using the following structure

```
typedef char stackitem;

struct stack {
stackitem  d;
struct stack *next;
};

typedef  struct stack ELEMENT;
typedef  ELEMENT   *POINTER;
```

I am having issues with printing my stack. What i am trying to do is create a temp stack where I print the element and then pop it off. however it seems to be removing it from the original stack which I dont want.

here is the code:

```
void print_stack(POINTER Top)
/*Print the contents of the stack. Do not modify the stack in any way. */
    {
        POINTER temp = Top;
    
        printf("Start printing the stack ...\n");
        
        while (temp != NULL){
        printf("%c\n",temp->d);
        pop(&temp);
        }

    }
void pop(POINTER *Top)
/* Remove the top item */
     {
        POINTER Top1 = *Top;
        if (Top != NULL)
        {
          *Top = Top1->next;
         // printf("Remove element %c\n", Top1->d);
          free(Top1);
        }
        else
          printf("Empty stack.\n");
     }
```

In my mind I am printing and popping from the temp pointer which shouldn't affect the original pointer top but when i insert into the stack and print it the first time it prints correctly and then the second time it prints nothing.

this is my main

```
POINTER top;
        top= (POINTER) NULL;
        stackitem A='A';
        stackitem B='B';
        push(&top,A);
        push(&top,B);
        print_stack(top); // prints B A 
        print_stack(top); // prints nothing
```

Any help with what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `print_stack()` method currently looks like this:

```c
void print_stack(POINTER Top) {
    POINTER temp = Top;

    printf("Start printing the stack ...\n");

    while (temp != NULL){
        printf("%c\n",temp->d);
        pop(&temp); // Calling `pop()` will modify your Stack
    }
}
```

You're calling `pop()` in your loop which modifies the stack; which is not good since `print_stack` is a read operation and should not be modifying the list. You can instead just increment the pointer so that it points to next value:

```c
void print_stack(POINTER Top) {
    POINTER temp = Top;

    printf("Start printing the stack ...\n");

    while (temp != NULL){
        printf("%c\n",temp->d);
        temp = temp->next; // Go to next element of stack
    }
}
```

I tested this code(I just needed to add additional `push` and `createNewStackNode` methods that weren't present:

```c
// ...

POINTER createNewStackNode(stackitem i) {
    POINTER newNode = (POINTER) malloc(sizeof(ELEMENT));
    newNode->d = i;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    return newNode;
}

void push(POINTER *top, char item) {
    POINTER curr = createNewStackNode(item);
    curr->next = *top;
    *top = curr;
}

// ...

int main() {
    POINTER top;
    top= (POINTER) NULL;
    stackitem A='A';
    stackitem B='B';
    push(&top,A);
    push(&top,B);
    print_stack(top); // prints B A 
    push(&top, 'C');
    push(&top, 'D');
    push(&top, 'E');
    push(&top, 'F');
    print_stack(top);
}
```

This prints the following output:

```
Start printing the stack ...
B
A
Start printing the stack ...
F
E
D
C
B
A
```

Answer (score 1):

As another user suggested, you don't create a second stack rather you just create a second pointer that shows you the same memory position as the original stack.

If I was you I would try to add the stack into an array ([you can search for guidance here](https://www.programming9.com/programs/c-programs/302-implementation-of-stack-using-array-in-c)) and then modify that array. That way your original stack will be unharmed.

Answer (score 0):

The `print_stack` function claims it doesn't modify the stack, but it does. For example, it calls `pop` which calls `free`, destroying the object on the top of the stack.

Comment: but wouldn't it be destroying the object from the temp stack?

Comment: @william_ There is no "temp stack". There's only one stack. Where do you think a copy of the stack is made? `POINTER temp = Top;` doesn't make a new stack, it just makes a new pointer that points to the very same stack.

Comment: ahh right, i was under the impression POINTER temp = Top would duplicate the stack. Any ideas how i could approach this?

Comment: @william_ It depends what you're trying to do. If you need to make a duplicate stack, write a function to make one. Otherwise, write a function that prints out the contents of the stack without modifying it.

Comment: do you have any advice for printing a stack without modifying it? something to point be in a direction

Comment: `POINTER temp=Top; while (temp!=NULL) { printf("%c", temp->d); temp = temp->next; }`